# How to get all liked objects of an user including posts, photos, urls with facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

This is cherrie. I am facing an issue, regarding facebook feed reading. I need to access all liked objects of an user including posts, photos, urls with graph api."me/likes" returns only pages. In earlier versions, we can achieve this using "user_activities" permissions, but now it is deprecated. Is there any way to achieve this, with present permissions. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to access all likes, you can only get access to Page likes as you have found out.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In that case, we wont be able to access user comments too. So, the maximum information that we can get about the user feed, is just what he/she shared on wall?

Comment: yes, you can only go through the feed and count, but that would be pretty pointless. you would never get access to every comment, only those who were made in your own timeline.